# Is it possible to use apple's HLS on tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I want to add live channel streaming to my **tvOS** app. the plan was to use apple's HLS protocol.

I tried apple's HLS code example from:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504/

I have added import AVFoundation then added this code.

```
func setupAssetDownload() {
   let hlsAsset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)
   let backgroundConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(
      withIdentifier: "assetDownloadConfigurationIdentifier")
   let assetURLSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: backgroundConfiguration,
      assetDownloadDelegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main())
   // Download a Movie at 2 mbps
   let assetDownloadTask = assetURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: hlsAsset, assetTitle: "My Movie",
      assetArtworkData: nil, options: [AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: 2000000])!
   assetDownloadTask.resume()
}
```

xcode gave me 'AVAssetDownloadURLSession' is unavailable

when i try the same code on iOS project it recognizes the AVAssetDownloadURLSession object.

according to apple documentation AVFoundeation supports HLS on tvOS.

what might be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently in tvOS 10, HLS playback is indeed supported, for example when loading a stream like `AVURLPlayer(url: "https://example.com/123.m3u8")`.

Unfortunately, `AVAssetDownloadURLSession` is not (yet) available right now. The Apple documentation mentioning HLS support is referring to the above.